# PHP include $_session var in an echo

Tags: php

So, I'm trying to echo a href with a link with a php string in the link. How would I go about doing this?

```
<? echo '<a href="profile.php?userid="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" style="border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 10px;">Profile</a>';?>
```

Comment: Any error ? What is the problem ? Can you tell us more or it's secret ?!

Comment: I cannot get what the question is

Comment: What's wrong with what you posted?

Comment: You do it like you have shown =p but get rid of the extra " after userid=.

Answer (score 1):

You're prematurely closing your href attribute in the link.  Remove the double quotes before your single quote to pull your variable in.

Change it to:

```
<? echo '<a href="profile.php?userid='.$_SESSION['userid'].'" style="border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 10px;">Profile</a>';?>
```